# Find indexOfObject from NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have an NSArray filled with custom objects.
Each object has several variables: pk, amount, date etc..

I want to fetch the object that has the highest number in the pk variable.
I can do this using:

```
 NSUInteger maximumpk = [[bets valueForKeyPath:@"@max.pk"] intValue];
```

This gives me the actual value from the highest pk. Now I need to get the index for that object. I have seen indexOfObject used when the array has just 1 variable of data, but how do I use it in this instance?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Darren, You may need to override the - (BOOL) isEqual(NSObject*) in your custom class. When you call indexOfObject in a NSArray it calls the isEqualMethod. So you can check the equality of the self.pk to the passing objects pk value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`-indexOfObjectPassingTest:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObjectPassingTest:), for example:

```
NSUInteger idx = [bets indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj pk] == maximumpk;
}];
```